# How do I unit test the view path?

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel

I have a redirection procedure. If an auth check fails, redirect the user to a specific page. If the auth check passes, load a view.

In my unit testing script, I am using Laravel's own assertRedirectedTo on the fail procedure, which works fine:

```
$this->assertRedirectedTo('users/create');
```

However, I want to check that if it passes, the view that is rendered is `users/index` - this is not a redirection, so I just want to check the path of the view to ensure it's correct.

I can't seem to find any way to return the view path in this form to assert against.

At present, I'm testing against the title, but I feel this will be redundant, because the title may change in future, and in that respect, the test should still pass.

Comment: Can you not use Redirect::to('users/create')?

Comment: Because this is a unit test, not application logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

```
$response = $this->call(...);

$view = $response->original;
$this->assertSame('users/index', $view->getName());
```

Similarly, you can use getPath() etc. on the [View](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/View/View.html) instance.

Comment: I had no idea you could getName on a view. Thanks for this.